# How to get Committed Date in vsts online?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the Scrum Template and one of the Status is Committed, but there is no field for Committed Date. I have: Created, Closed, Accepted Date..

How can I get it?

Comment: What methods have you tried and what trouble are you having? Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for doing independent research.

Comment: VSTS provide a status and I want to know when a Product Backlog item change to this status. So I can calculate the Lead Time from the itens. So I'm asking how can I get the date that an item change to the Committed state... This is an independent research??

Comment: Please read this and update your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this for questions that have Code, this is a question about a tool.. I search the field and didn't find, so I'm asking how to do this.

Comment: So you're trying to write a work item query? You didn't specify that.

Comment: If I can get this value with a query, the query should be the answer... But I don't know how to get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no field for you to get a work item status changed date. But There has other two ways for you to get the date.

#### Option 1: by REST API

You can use [get a list of work items revision](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/revisions#get-a-list-of-work-items-revisions) to get a work item revisions by

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/id/revisions?api-version=1.0
```

Then use `System.State`, `System.CreatedDate` and `System.ChangedDate` parameters in output to calculate the lead time between two status.

#### Option 2: manually calculate by view a work item history

You can view a WIT change history by this way:

1. Open a work item, and click **History**.

[image]

2. Then you can view the work item status changed date apparently. And calculate lead time manually.

[image]